# single-qubit gate followed by a single-qubit error

Tags: quantum-state

What are the ways to rewrite a single-qubit gate follow by a signle-qubit error?

Comment: What kind of error are we working with? Incoherent or Coherent?

Comment: Asked and answered in the book [Quantum Computing: A Gentle Introduction](https://books.google.ca/books?id=iYX6AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA293&lpg=PA293#v=onepage&q&f=false), chapter 12 exercises; is this a homework question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that your single qubit gate is $U$, and it's followed by some noise operator $A$. So, overall, you've implemented $AU$. You want to know if this can be written in the form $UB$ where $B$ is a new noise operator. So, you just want to solve
$$
AU=UB.
$$
To rearrange for $B$, just pre-multiply by $U^\dagger$:
$$
B=U^\dagger AU.
$$
As a bonus, if $A$ was unitary, you can easily see that $B$ is unitary. If $A$ is  Kraus operator, then you might have a trace preserving property such as
$$
\sum_iA_i^\dagger A_i=I,
$$
then this also applies to your new description:
$$
\sum_iB_i^\dagger B_i=\sum_iU^\dagger A_i^\dagger UU^\dagger A_iU=U^\dagger\left(\sum_iA_i^\dagger A_i\right)U=U^\dagger IU=I.
$$